# CSS, 2 divs, 1 expanding 1 fixed, but needs to wrap

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, and I need both of them to have a minimum size of about 300px.
I need the left div to stretch out to the available space, however if the window size is too small, then the right div needs to drop below.   This is what I have currently, but Im not sure what to change.

```
<style>
.bbleft {
    min-height: 237px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.bbright {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 237px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: does any of our answers help you at all..?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

http://jsfiddle.net/fxWg7/790/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        content fixed width
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        content flexible width
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    background: #aafed6;
}

.right {
    float: none; /* not needed, just for clarification */
    background: #e8f6fe;
    /* the next props are meant to keep this block independent from the other floated one */
    min-width:300px;
    width: auto;
    max-width:500px; /* not neccessary */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think this is what I need, however it's the right side that is statically sized, and the left side that needs to expand.

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e865h/)

A css3 approach..

Flexible left div.
Right div drops when page too small.
Left div fills up the rest of the space.

HTML

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    width:100%;
}
body div{
    min-width:300px;
    float:left;
}

.left{
    width: calc( 100% - 310px );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple use this

```
.bbleft {
    min-height: 237px;
    overflow:hidden;
float:left;width:100%;
}
```